# WPF logging in with B2C

Tags: c#, wpf, azure-ad-b2c

I am writing a WPF application, the user has to log in using Azure B2C using this code.

```
AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
var app = App.PublicClientApp;
try
{
    authResult = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(App.ApiScopes)
        .WithParentActivityOrWindow(new WindowInteropHelper(this.MainWindow).Handle)
        .ExecuteAsync();
```

When the user closes the login screen, I cannot find a way of capturing this, also when they have logged in the browser stays open and shows a message of "Authentication complete. You can return to the application. Feel free to close this browser tab" which I would prefer didn't appear.

I have searched and tried various different other parameters for AcquiteTokenInteractive but I don't seem to be able to get them to work
Hopefully somebody can help

Comment: Why aren't they inputting username and password in wpf? You can just http post to azure b2c and get your security token for later rest calls.

Comment: Thanks @Andy could you point me at an example - we struggled to do this, so took the approach outline above

Comment: Notice there's user name and password in the http post here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-user-flow